# Most understandable notation for reduction and oxidation potentials

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

Nowadays a lot of electrochemistry is done using just electrode potentials (i.e. reduction potentials), so if in doubt the notation $E^o$ tends to imply a reduction potential. However, some chemists use the perfectly acceptable convention that oxidation reactions are accompanied with oxidation potentials.

I wondered whether anyone could inform me about the most unambiguous or widely used conventions for indicating which type of potential is being employed when written next to a half equation.

For instance, for the **oxidation** half equation $Ag \rightarrow Ag^+ + e^-$, I could write the associated potential in a number of ways:

1. $E_{Ag^+/Ag} = +0.80V$ - the electrode potential of the $Ag^+/Ag$ couple
2. $E_{red}(Ag^+/Ag) = +0.80V$ - the reduction potential of the $Ag^+/Ag$ couple
3. $E_{ox}(Ag^+/Ag) = -0.80V$ - the oxidation potential of the $Ag^+/Ag$ couple
4. Often, just $E$, or some other notation!

I think the notation in points 1 through 3 is fairly clear, with the first two applicable to the European convention and the third applicable to the American convention, when written next to the oxidation equation. However I was wondering if anyone more experienced could advise as to what the most common conventions in the field are!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your textbook author is confusing and still teaching American & European conventions. It is obsolete now. I will show you how oxidation potentials were quoted by American electrochemists in the 1950s-60s. Have a look at the table [Latimer's book: Oxidation States of the Elements and their Potentials in Aqueous Solutions pg 340](https://archive.org/details/oxidationstateso00lati/page/340/mode/1up). This was a very famous book of its time. Latimer and Gibbs had great influence on American science and thermodynamics.

I would say you should stick to only (1). Your number 3 is not correct because you are still writing the cell as reduction. The correct version would be

$E_{ox}(Ag/Ag^+) = -0.80V$ - the oxidation potential of the $Ag/Ag^+$ couple, so that you are consistent.

Also make sure your instructor is aware of these things (American European conventions, and that the sign of the electrode potential is an electrostatic one, and that electrode potential does not care how the equation is written. You seem to know more than an average PhD student). I will not be surprised, your instructor is not a trained electrochemist, he/she may not be aware of these subtleties.

Also note that the small "o" on E, indicates standard conditions.

[image: Oxidation potentials]

Comment: I wonder, why is it that number (3) is incorrect? The oxidation potential is the emf of a cell where the redox couple in question is on the left side of the cell (undergoing oxidation), and is well defined independent of the choice of convention. I personally wouldn't use (3) (like you say, the convention of labelling reactions with oxidation potentials is rarely used anymore), but just for completeness' sake isn't it still a correct formulation?

Comment: @JamesWirth, I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ah, I thought a couple was an unordered pair of species (i.e. $/^+ \equiv ^+/$) which is just written in the form / for consistency. Because then, we could always speak of the electrode potential of the $^+/$ couple without needing to worry about whether the cell reaction is a reduction or oxidation. That is to say we can always refer to the $X/X^-$ electrode no matter the reaction occurring there.

Comment: So if $Ag^+/Ag$ represents a half cell which might perform two different half reactions, then its electrode potential is the emf if we connect that half cell on the right wrt SHE, the oxidation potential of that couple the emf if we connect that half cell on the left wrt SHE, etc. It actually appears important that the order of the couple does not imply a particular half equation.

Comment: "So if Ag+/Ag represents a half cell which might perform two $different$ half reactions", this does not make any electrochemical sense. It is one and only one half cell whether there is an oxidation or reduced. You can only say, Ag+/Ag  can either be an anode or a cathode.

Comment: I will give you an example. Let us say water boils at 100 C. Now if I write H2O (l) <=> H2O (g), and I write T_H2O = +100 C, now reverse the equation, H2O(g) <=> H2O(l), can we write, T_H2O = -100 C? The is true when people try to reverse the sign of electrode potentials.

Comment: I think the confusion is arising from abbreviating the half cell. The typical procedure is that if you consider the half cell as an anode, you write it as an oxidation i.e., Ag ->Ag^+ + e, but don't change the sign of the electrode potential. The sign change occurs automatically when you calculate the E_cell=E_cathode-E_anode

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more careful. I meant that $Ag^+/Ag$ is simply referring to a redox couple (an unordered pair of two species), and not a half equation in a particular direction. The  $Ag^+/Ag$ redox couple might be fixed at either the cathode or anode, depending on how we connect our circuit. What I’m saying is that even if the half reaction is an oxidation, the redox couple at that electrode is still $Ag^+/Ag$.

Comment: So in that sense, I see no need to reverse the ordering of the redox couple to $E_{ox} (Ag/Ag^+)$, since this is completely equivalent to the expression I wrote - because redox couples don’t equate to half equations!

Comment: Well, you are right that the electrode potentials do not care how the half cell is written, but there are norms in a given field. People do stick to writing certain conventions. For example if I invent a new symbol for integration, mathematicians will reject my proposal . The notation you are using is not canonical either. Today, $E$  implies a reduction half cell with respect to hydrogen. This has been settled by electrochemists and decided by IUPAC. I am not an electrochemist, but I was lucky to have a fine electrochemistry professor. I have personally studied these conventions for a decade.

Comment: If you are really interested in going deep into these sign conventions, their origins and the sources of confusion, search the Journal of Chemical Education on the sign of electrode potentials. There are many useful articles. Your university should have access to them. Don't search the web, search academic articles. The web is full of non-sense especially on historical matters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105643/discussion-between-james-wirth-and-m-farooq).